# Are there any c# .Net Framework projects that can provide callbacks/responses to my .Net Core project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .Net Core API project (Angular front end) and it is missing certain libraries that are part of .Net Framework. So I need to have a project I can call from my .Net Core project to run some .Net Framework code. But I need to have callbacks/responses from the .Net Framework project that I can read in my .Net Core app so I know what's going on.

What's the best project type to allow communication between the two apps that will give me the responses (callbacks) I need? ex. success, error, etc

I could create a simple console app but then I'd be listening to the console output, right?
Seems like there would be better options.

**UPDATE** - to be more specific - I want to call a web service (WCF). The web service is for documents to be uploaded. .Net Core doesn't support MTOM, which is something that is needed to make the call to the service. I can't seem to be able to make connection because of "the difference in libraries"?
between the client (me) and the server(them). So I thought creating a .Net Framework project that I know will work and calling it from my .Net Core project is the only current solution?

Comment: Try "Class Library"  project template.

Comment: Which "certain libraries"?

Comment: You probably don't actually need to do that. What version of .NET Core are you using? What libraries are you wanting to use that you can't find? Include some more details, [mcve], etc. Take a look at [ask].

Comment: I just added a little bit of additional info to my post under UPDATE

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no way to directly reference a .NET Framework project from .NET Core. You could create an adapter project using .NET Framework that exposes a REST API, and call that from your .NET Core app, microservices-style. It's slower, more complicated, and probably not ideal. Sorry.

Comment: I know a library will not work, that's the point, what else is there to use to communicate between my 2 projects when 1 is .Net Core and the other is .Net Framework? I can only think of writing a console app and reading/writing to the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a .NET web api project and have the .Net Core project call it using HTTP requests.  Basically the the core project would act as a proxy in that it would act as a http client to the .NET webapi project when the special libraries are needed.

The same model has worked many times for me.  Like when we used proprietary dlls that are not certified for core yet. Angular calls core controller, core controller proxies request to .NET controller using http request.

Resource on httpclient in core:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: cool thanks man! If I have anymore questions can I ask you in the comment section?

Comment: Sure.  It is usually pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi Ali. Can any of what you recommend be done on a Mac? I know .Net Framework won't run on a Mac. My two projects (Angular/>Net Core Web Api) are both running and being developed on my Mac. I guess I could switch to a Windows machine, unless you know a different solution?

Comment: I know it can be done however I haven't attempted the same configuration.  I have done similar development which required that I host a linux dev system on windows desktop using VirtualBox.  You could run a virtual machine environment such as VirtualBox to emulate a separate windows host  and configure network forwarding, else I think the current alternative is to look into containers such as docker to achieve the same result.